Sci-fi movie on HBO from the early to mid 1980s that freaked me out as a kid
So, this was maybe 30-35 years ago and here's all I can remember.
It starts out with a young couple making out in a car overlooking the town.  As the couple is preoccupied, a UFO lands.
When one of the kids returns home, all the lights are on, the tv is on, dinner is still on the table.  He goes into the bathroom and I think the water was running and as he is investigating, this alien hand grabs him from behind the shower curtain.  The camera switches to an outside view of the house as he is sceaming and lights are flashing.
That freaked me out and the adults turned it off.  To this day, if I get up to pee in the middle of the night I have to look behind the shower curtain first. I forgot to mention that there is no one home at the house... Oh, and I guess I am supposed to say it was in English and in color. 
Anyway, after 30 or 35 years, it's time to watch that movie... if I can ever figure out what it was called.

Pretty sure you described the start of Strange Invaders from 1983, though it's not a shower curtain, so you don't have to be afraid anymore. :)
It starts with a young couple making out in a truck as a UFO lands. The girl returns home and sees that the TV's on and no one is there. The young man returns home and sees the same thing: No one's there but the TV is on, there's food on the table and there's a toy frog swimming in the bath. Right after the bath scene, he tries to call someone and an alien hand's shadow appears on the wall behind him. He sees it and we cut to an outside shot with him screaming and lights flashing in the windows.
So there's no need to fear shower curtains anymore! Just walls. You don't have  those, right? >:)
The entire movie is currently available on Youtube. Here's the trailer:




Holy cow that's it.  Lol.  It's funny how something can stick with you for 32 years.  Afterall this time i have been liberated.... No longer will I have an irrational fear of shower curtains!  Thank you so much!!!
